# which is the best gem for push notifications on android with ruby on rails 4+?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, push-notification

actually, i want to send push notification on submit button. when the user presses the button then on the android phone getting a push notification.

Answer (score 1):

I have used `gem 'fcm'`

The FCM gem lets your ruby backend send notifications to Android and iOS devices via Firebase Cloud Messaging.

https://github.com/spacialdb/fcm